# Backbone.js: Is there a way to set a property for all models in a collection when creating the collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am wondering if there is any way to pass in a value when I instantiate a new Collection, which will be set as a property on all new models that are added to the collection.  E.g.,

```
allSchools = [/* list of schools */];
this.schoolTypes = new Backbone.Collection([], { model:SchoolType }); //pass in allSchools here, somehow
this.schoolTypes.add({name:'New SchoolType'});
```

where the newly added Model will have a this.allSchools (or this.options.allSchools or something like that).  Seems there should be a simple enough way to do this?  Currently I'm just accessing a global allSchools object but its not very modular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mu mentioned in his comment, models have a built-in .collection property.  So, if I set a property on the collection, I can access it from any model within the collection like so:

```
schoolType = schoolTypes.at(0);
allSchools = schoolType.collection.allSchools;
```

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the best way, but you could add a backward link to the model to let it access it's parent collection :

```
this.schoolType.allSchools = allSchools;
var col = this.schoolType;
this.schoolType.each(function(el,i){
    el.collection = col;
});
// ...
// then access all the schools from your SchoolType model `m` : 
if(m.collection)
    var allSchools = m.collection.allSchools;
```

Comment: The models in a collection already have a `.collection` (see http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/HxutA/), I don't think this is documented behavior though (at least I couldn't find any supporting documentation with a cursory search).

Comment: mu, cool. That's probably what i'm looking for... I could just set the allSchools as a property on the collection, and then the models can access it via the .collection.allSchools.  Write it up as an answer and assuming it works, its yours :)